# How to implement a fixed rate poller with ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

Given the following class:

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {
    public static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 4;

    public boolean running;
    public ScheduledExecutorService ses;

    public void startPolling() {
        this.ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
        this.ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        // ... Do something ...
        running = false;
    }
}
```

The `ScheduledExecutorService` has a core thread pool size of 4 but will more than one poller thread ever be created? Since `this` is passed into `scheduleAtFixedRate` does that mean there will only ever be one thread - or does something more complex happen behind the scenes?

And 2 bonus questions:-

1. Should `running` be `static`?
2. Is `CORE_POOL_SIZE` redundant?

Comment: running cannot be static

Comment: running indicates if that particular thread is running hence it has to be an instance variable - cannot be static.

Comment: Thanks. But my confusion is that I will only have a single `poller` instance - does that mean only one thread will be used by the scheduler?

Comment: There will not be more than one thread. In fact, the worker-thread management inside the SES is almost useless. In your case, with only one Runnable, having more threads only makes sense at all if they run longer than their fixed rate interval. However, the next invocation of the runnable will only be scheduled after it has run, so you can not run multiple invocation of the same runnable concurrently.

Comment: @RalfH It is not the case - with an initial delay of 0, at least two threads will be created immediately I believe (one to run now, one to run later). And as new runs are executed, the whole core pool size will be used.

Comment: @assylias so be it, I am too lazy/busy to write a test now :)

Comment: @assylias  Threads are not created immediately. They are created on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The ScheduledExecutorService has a core thread pool size of 4 but will more than one poller thread ever be created?

It depends - if you run your program long enough, it will probably create 4 threads. If you quit after running your scheduled task only once or twice, you might only see 2 or 3 threads.

Why does it matter?

One way to monitor thread creation is to provide your own `ThreadFactory`:

```
this.ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE, new ThreadFactory() {

            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                System.out.println("Creating thread");
                return new Thread(r);
            }
        });
```

> Should running be static?

It depends on what you want to achieve... Since you are not really it using in your example it is hard to say. You might need to make it static if you have several instances of Poller and you want them to not run concurrently for example.

Whether it is static or not, if you use it as a flag, you should make it volatile to ensure visibility.

> Is CORE_POOL_SIZE redundant?

Not sure what you mean. It is a mandatory parameter so you need to provide a value. If you know for sure that no two execution will run concurrently, you could only have one thread. That will also prevent concurrent execution (so if one scheduled task needs to start but another is already running, the new one will be delayed).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. Still a little bit confused though. I'll only be instantiating one poller. So how do the extra threads get created? Regarding the redundancy q, I'm presuming from the replies that only one thread can be running at a time - so what is the point of having more than one thread in the pool?

Comment: @SteveChambers They get created because the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor creates new threads until it reaches the core pool size. The only reason why you would only want one thread is if you want to prevent concurrent execution of your tasks (thread creation being very cheap, having 1 or 4 threads won't make much difference from a performance/memory perspective). If not, allowing more than one thread will help your tasks run "on time", even if a previously scheduled task is still running.

Comment: Think I may be missing something here! Let's say I instantiate `poller` and then call `poller.startPolling()`. It passes itself (`this`) into `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. `running` isn't static and refers to the single `poller` instance so if there is more than one thread, which one does `poller` represent? And how would I find out about whether any of the others are running?

Comment: @SteveChambers Your question is a little confusing. There is only one instance of your Runnable, but multiple threads can run it concurrently.

Comment: Oh I see! Think you may have just put your finger on the source of all my confusion. Am now thinking the `running` flag could be useless since it could be turned on by Thread #1 starting and then turned straight off again by Thread #2 finishing so would be `false` even if Thread #1 hasn't finished.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes that could happen.

Comment: So it looks like I need a `static int runningCount` that gets incremented at the start of `run()` and decremented at the end ...or is there a better way?

Comment: @SteveChambers Why do you need it (what do you want to do with that variable)?

Comment: It's so I know when a pausing method has actually taken effect. Stackoverflow is suggesting moving this discussion into chat - could post a code fragment there. Would you be OK with that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26250/discussion-between-assylias-and-steve-chambers)

Answer (score 3):

**scheduleAtFixedRate (Runnable, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit timeunit)**

This method schedules a task to be executed periodically. The task is executed the first time after the initialDelay, and then recurringly every time the period expires.

If any execution of the given task throws an exception, the task is no longer executed. If no exceptions are thrown, the task will continue to be executed until the ScheduledExecutorService is shut down.

**If a task takes longer to execute than the period between its scheduled executions, the next execution will start after the current execution finishes. The scheduled task will not be executed by more than one thread at a time.**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put your executor service in `Runnable` class?
You should separate your `ScheduledExecutorService` as Singleton rather than being variable of runnable class.

Remind this `ScheduledExecutorService` is a thread container, so when you code this

```
this.ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
```

it will create a lot of threads base on value of the size on the same time, when you put this code

```
this.ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

the `ScheduledExecutorService` will randomly pick a thread which idle to run this class every 1 second until it is finish. if you put `sleep` in run method that is longer than value of period time pass to scheduled thread, it wont create another thread until the 1st thread is finish. So if you want multiple thread run this `Poller` on the same time, then create multiple `Poller` instance and pass it to `ScheduledExecutorService`

`CORE_POOL_SIZE` its not redundant for me, its good to be a constant which value taken from configuration file.

Should running be static? 
it's depends on what you need. if you intend to create multiple instance of `Poller` then u shouldn't